# Lightning app violates CSP directive

Tags: lightning-apps, aura

I am getting the following error while trying to preview my lightning app:

[image]

I am trying to set the CSP directive in my app like this but I'm not sure I am putting it in the right place. I have tried putting this meta tag in both the app and the component. Is there a different place that this needs to go?

```
<aura:application >
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src 'self' https://api.bluetail.salesforce.com https://staging.bluetail.salesforce.com https://preprod.bluetail.salesforce.com" />
     <ltng:require scripts="/resources/BarcodePageResources" />
     <c:BarcodeScanner />
</aura:application>
```

Comment: remove the `'self'` from `'self' https` and try

Comment: @Ashwani Just tried that and got the same exact error. Am I putting the meta tag in the right file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSP issue ending up not being a problem after I corrected the url for my resource. The issue was resolved after changing my code to this:

```
<aura:application >
     <ltng:require scripts="/resource/BarcodePageResources/quagga.js" />
     <c:BarcodeScanner />
</aura:application>
```

Comment: Great - I would also recommend that you leverage $Resource which provides fine grained versioning support: <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.BarcodePageResources + '/quagga.js'}" />

Answer (score 5):

You cannot change the CSP of a lightning app - it is critical to Salesforce's security architecture and is set via the CSP header which always takes precedence over the meta equiv.

The good news is that there is a feature coming in Spring'17 that will allow you to add your own endpoints to connect-src for you org via Setup.

Comment: The resource I am trying to access is a static resource in my org. What would be the correct way of accessing it and not violating the CSP?

Comment: @DougChasman, any news on how to add a `connect-src` in the Setup menu?
*Edit:* found it, it's called "CSP Trusted Site" in the Setup menu.